# Motor disability – In Android Home or “All Apps”, tapping on right edge = swipe to the left – Tap bottom in Chrome = swipe up/page down?

Tags: chrome-for-android, samsung-nexus-10, accessibility

Microsoft has the Sticky Keys accessibility option so that you don’t have to hold down a modifier. Too much holding down, like in mouse dragging, and swiping on a touchscreen can be bothersome for people who suffer from a repetitive strain injury, or other people with motor disabilities.

On the Android Home screen or “All Apps”, tapping on the right edge = swipe to the left, which moves you to the next screen on the right.

When browsing Chrome, or YouTube, is there a way that you can similarly touch somewhere near the bottom edge of the screen to execute a swipe up (page down)? Perhaps an accessibility option can be turned on to add a page down button in the Navigation Bar?

It would be like browsing a webpage on the desktop, and instead of just tapping the space bar, or page down buttons, you have to keep swiping upwards on the screen.

Thanks.

(Posted on Accessibility Google Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/accessible/YM1pNjRcD1Y)